# LifecycleOwner also if I change Activity

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle

I m trying to build a code to get position of the smartphone from a private SDK.
So i m build this code:

```
nextomePhoenixSdk.getLocalizationLiveData().observe((LifecycleOwner) myActivity, new androidx.lifecycle.Observer(){

            public void onChanged(Object var1) {
                this.onChanged((NextomePosition)var1);
            }

            public final void onChanged(NextomePosition it) {
                Log.e("POSITION FROM NEXTOME", "X: " + it.getX() + " Y: " + it.getY());
            }
        });
```

Now if I try to start the application and I have myActivity as current View the new position will be notified by onChanged method.

But if I try to set in background my application or simply I try to change activity, the observer end to notify me new position though the service continue to run.
Now I want to find a view to get new position every time also if the app is in background mode or if the user change the activity.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are observing live data using a lifecycle observer that is tied to your `Activity`s lifecycle. When your `Activity` is stopped (covered, in background, etc.) you will no longer get any updates from the live data. That's exactly how this is supposed to work. Because your `Activity` is no longer visible, there is no point in passing any updates to it, because it can't show the data to the user. As soon as your `Activity` is visible again, you will continue to get live data updates.

This works exactly as intended.